# Slow Facebook scrolling on Firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox, google-chrome, facebook

Welcome. I used Ubuntu a few years, but eventually switched to OS X, not fixing for almost five years puzzle of Firefox on Ubuntu.

Regardless of whether you use the stable version, or test, scrolling the main page Facebook runs terribly slow. In Chrome and Chromium problem does not occur, but if it's my parents or friends, which I recommended system complain because they just prefer Firefox. Tell me what to do?

Naturally, the problem occurs on powerful and very weak computers, without distinction, whether the system is 32 or 64 bit. Currently, I see the problem in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: As a senior software developer with over 25 years of experience I am absolutely floored by the rock-bottom quality in performance of glorified chat applications like Facebook.  At this point I'd rather an mIRC atavism than see the train-wreck of interactive web apps continue on its present trajectory.  There is absolutely no excuse for this garbage, none whatsoever.  You don't have to entertain any degree of Stockholm syndrome here, so don't.  Regardless of who implements the solution, this is Facebook's problem, full stop.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that this is not because of system speed, but because of how Firefox is configured to handle scrolling.

Start by typing `about:config` in the address bar. This will provide you with access to detailed Firefox settings.

Once there, search for `scroll` and you will find tons of values that address scrolling speed, animations, and behaviour.

If you are scrolling with mouse wheel, you may significantly increase scroll speed by increasing the value of `mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount`. This setting is the amount by which a page is scrolled when you turn your wheel for one tick.

If scrolling is slow when using the scrollbar, you may wish to disable smooth scrolling animation, which may be causing some slight lag. To achieve that, set `general.smoothScroll` to `false`.

It may be required to restart Firefox before these changes take effect.